# Template invoice PDF - additional field tax rate

Tags: magento-2.1

Here is code my template invoice PDF.

```
<div>
<div class="body" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 29.7cm; margin: 0 auto; color: #555555; background: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;">
<div class="clearfix header" style="padding: 10px 0; margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;">
<div id="company" style="float: right; text-align: right; width: 49%;">
<h2 class="name" style="font-size: 1.4em; font-weight: normal; margin: 0;">COMPANY</h2>
<div>Address</div>
<div><a href="mailto:mail@email.eu">mail@email.eu</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div id="details" class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
<div id="client" style="padding-left: 6px; border-left: 6px solid #000; float: left; width: 49%;">
<div class="to" style="color: #777777;">KLIENT:</div>
<div class="name">{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</div>
</div>
<div id="invoice" style="float: right; text-align: right; width: 49%;">
<h1 style="color: #000; font-size: 2.4em; line-height: 1em; font-weight: normal; margin: 0  0 10px 0;">FAKTURA NR {{var invoice.increment_id}}</h1>
<div class="date" style="font-size: 1.1em; color: #777777;">Data wystawienia faktury:{{var invoice.created_at}}</div>
<div class="date" style="font-size: 1.1em; color: #777777;">Status: {{var order.status}}</div>
</div>
</div>
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

how to display on invoice additional field TAX RATE for example 0% ?

Maybe someone can send a ready template?